# Difference between 'spatially' and 'instantaneously' independent

Tags: independence, spatial

For a multivariate time series

$$\underline{y}(t)=[y_1(t) \dots y_n(t)]^T$$

What is the difference between the components $y_i(t)$ being spatially independent and instantaneously independent?

Comment: I believe I know the answer/have an idea, but I will leave it to see whether any answers agree with this first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The components are instantaneously uncorrelated if 
$$
E[y_i(t_1) y_j(t_2)] = 0
$$
for all $i \not= j$ and for all $t_1,t_2$ and when $i = j$ :
$$
E[y_i(t_1) y_i(t_2)] = 0
$$
for all $t_1 \not= t_2$.

The components are spatially uncorrelated if
$$
E[y_i(t) y_j(t)] = 0
$$
for all $i \not= j$ (assuming a change in index corresponds to a spatial change).

[Note that correlation is not quite the same thing as statistical independence.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence)

Comment: I agree, but I would like to point out that you implicitly assume that the components $y_i(t)$ have zero mean. If this were not the case, then the definitions you gave refer to orthogonality instead of uncorrelatedness, because $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated if $E[XY]=E[X]E[Y]$, and they're orthogonal if $E[XY]=0$. Obviously, if either $E[X]=0$ or $E[Y]=0$, orthogonality and uncorrelatedness are equivalent.

Comment: @MattL.: Good point!

Comment: Should it not say 'instantaneously uncorrelated ... for all $i \neq j$ and for all $t_1 , t_2$?

Comment: Hmmm. Toughy.  Yes, but...  Let me update.

Comment: Can you explain the line $E[y_i(t_1),y_i(t_2))]=0$ for all $t_1 \neq t_2$. Why is this necessary? Would this be omitted if the components were instantaneously $mutually$ uncorrelated.

Comment: It just means that $y_i$ is white (uncorrelated with itself, except at the same time).